# fix the code in C#

Tags: c#, variables, local-variables

I have this following C# code:

```
double eps=0.1, low=1, y0=0, x, y, high, muchlat, answer, ribua;
Console.WriteLine("Enter x");
x = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
high = y = x;
muchlat = Math.Abs(y - y0) ;
if (x < 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("X can't be less than zero, press any key to exit");

}
else if (muchlat > eps)
{

    while  (muchlat > eps)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(y);
        y0 = y;
        y = (high + low) /2;
        ribua = Math.Pow(y,2);
        if (ribua == x)
        {
            answer = x;
        }
        else if (ribua > x)
        {
            high =y;
        }
        else if (ribua < x)
        {
            low =y;
        }
        else if (muchlat < eps)
        {
            answer = y;
            break;
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(answer);
Console.ReadLine();
```

When I try to debug the program, I got this message
"Use of unassigned local variable 'answer' (CS0165)", my question is how can I fix it, and where is the problem?

Comment: Assign a value to the variable `answer` before you use it.

Comment: Please next time try to search for error (CS0165) before asking question... And make sample smaller... even smaller than small... 2 lines should have been enough for this question.

Answer (score 5):

Answer is never initialized.

```
double eps=0.1, low=1, y0=0, x=0, y=0, high=0, muchlat=0, answer=0, ribua=0;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! my quastion now is  why this is endless loop? (the while loop)? how can I fix it so when it get the anser it will stop running?

Comment: That should probably be asked as a new question...but you're never updating the values of `muchlat` and `eps` and your only `break` command will never execute because it's the inverse of your `while` statement. Also, I'm not entirely sure what the logic is behind this code - i.e., what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3):

Simply define the value for answer to 0 when declaring it. That should fix it.